# Query OSM nodes not member of way in Overpass

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api, overpass-turbo

How can I query OSM nodes that are not member of ways?
I want to get the nodes which tagged with (traffic_calming=bump) and not member of any ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Querying for nodes which are not part of a way is covered by the [city limit street signs example](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_API_by_Example#City_limit_street_signs):

```
[bbox:{{bbox}}];
node[traffic_calming=bump] -> .allnodes;
way[highway](bn.allnodes);
node(w)[traffic_calming=bump] -> .waynodes;
(.allnodes; - .waynodes;);
out;
```

Comment: `node(around:15)[traffic_calming=bump]` is not needed here, there's no requirement to find those traffic_calming nodes within 15m of existing traffic_calming nodes.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a different approach which I based on the [Orphaned nodes](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_API_by_Example#Orphaned_nodes_.28nodes_without_tags.2C_not_part_of_any_way_or_relation.29) example:

```
[bbox:{{bbox}}];
rel; > -> .r;
way; > -> .w;
(( node["traffic_calming=bump"]; - node.r; );  - node.w; );
out meta;
```